# Swift change backgroundcolor and have rounded corners in an UIVIew?

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit

I have a problem changing the backgroundcolor and making rounded corners the same time.

```
droppedView.roundCorners(corners: .bottomLeft, radius: 7)
droppedView.roundCorners(corners: .bottomRight, radius: 7)
droppedView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
```

When I do it like this, my View has rounded corners, but there is no backgroundcolor.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is it a view you are applying the modifiers to or a UI Shape? In that case use `.fill()` and then `.roundCorners()`

Comment: Where does 'roundCorners' come from?

Comment: Add `UIKit` to your army of tags so that you won't mislead others.

Comment: thanks for your help but unfortunately it has not yet worked.

Comment: yes I am trying to apply it to an UIView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution this may helps you

```
        droppedView.clipsToBounds = true
        droppedView.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        droppedView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
        droppedView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
```

Answer (score 1):

#### UIKit

You could use `layer.cornerRadius` in UIKit:

```
    droppedView.clipsToBounds = true
    droppedView.layer.cornerRadius = 7

    droppedView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
    droppedView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
```

---

#### SwiftUI

`clip.Shape` is available in SwiftUI.

First, create File View+Extensions.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners))
    }
}

struct RoundedCorner: Shape {

    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

and then, go to `View.Swift`:

```
Rectangle().cornerRadius(50, corners: .bottomRight)
Rectangle().cornerRadius(50, corners: .bottomLeft)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.clipShape`:

```
droppedView.background(Color.systemGray6)
droppedView.clipShape(Rectangle().roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 7))
```

Comment: What is Rectangle()?  clipShape with UIKit?